# Not understanding how JSP magic works

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-3.0

I am just stuck with the following code.

Here is the `contextListener` in my Web dynamic app:

```
package ua.nure.sanin.web.listener;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@WebListener
public class ServletContextListenerImpl implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(System.class);

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        LOG.info("contextDestroyed");

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        LOG.info("contextInitialized");
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("lang_en");
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("lang", rb);

    }

}
```

I put `ResourceBundler` as attribute.

Now, I have an JSP page which works well. It contains such code:

```
${lang.welcomeCoffee}
```

**Question:**

How  does `${lang.welcomeCoffee}`  work?

If it is supposed to be:

```
request.getServletContext().getAttribute("lang")).getString("welcomeCoffee");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Comment: but ResourseBundler does not contains getWelcomeCoffe method or field.

Comment: Do you have `welcomeCoffee` as a field in `ResourseBundler`?

Comment: ResourseBundler does not have such field.

Comment: look at generated source code for this jsp

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not

`request.getServletContext().getAttribute("lang").getString("welcomeCoffee");`

Starting from version 3 of EL, you can customize the expression language processing in several ways. Possibly your server knows how to read resource bundles.

See [What's New With Expression Language In Java EE 7](http://pt.slideshare.net/reza_rahman/whats-new-with-expression-language-in-java-ee-7) for an overview.